# R: Dynamic reference of column name from xlsx namedregion using get() in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose this is my data, it is just a sample and not the original data.

```
dark = data.table(cake = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c3", "c3"), note = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "h", "i", "j", "j", "k", "l", "m", "m"), walk = c(183, 789, 753, 130, 126, 44, 325, 710, 307, 264, 708, 769, 742, 559, 181, 138))
road <- data.table(rab = c(0, 10, 50, 100, 120, 150, 160, 200, 400, 450, 550, 560, 700, 800, 900), cat = c("t",5,7,"y","t",1,2,4,"t","y","u","u","u",6,7))
```

And this is something which needs to be done.

```
dark[road,"menti" :=.(i.cat) ,   on = .(walk >= rab) ]
```

and I am very happy with this code. this works perfectly.

Now the problem is that if I try to make a dynamic reference for the column `walk` the code throws error.

For e.g. both of the below code doesn't runs.

```
dark[road,"menti" :=.(i.cat) ,   on = .(get(fromexcel) >= rab) ]
dark[road,"menti" :=.(i.cat) ,   on = .(eval(parse(text = fromexcel)) >= rab) ]
```

here is the code for `fromexcel` which I am currently using.

```
> library(openxlsx)
> fromexcel<-read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "//dfgygsad/Book1.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet2",namedRegion = "field",colNames = FALSE)[,1]
> fromexcel
[1] "walk"
```

error is

```
Error in colnamesInt(x, names(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='get(fromexcel)'
```

Appreciate if your answers can solve this issue without changing the code but only making this dynamic reference work.

Comment: FYI, I removed the [tag:openxlsx] tag because it wasn't really relevant to the problem or the solution. That is, `fromexcel` could have been self-defined, from a `textInput` in a shiny app, scraped from a web page somewhere, it doesn't matter. If you feel this is in error, my apologies, feel free to add it back.

Comment: No worries. Thanks. However I am still looking for a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strings in the `on=` portion.

```r
# original, for reference
dark[road,"menti" :=.(i.cat), on = .(walk >= rab) ]
fromexcel
# [1] "walk"
dark[road,"menti2" :=.(i.cat), on = paste(fromexcel, ">= rab") ]
#       cake   note  walk  menti menti2
#     <char> <char> <num> <char> <char>
#  1:      1      a   183      2      2
#  2:      2      b   789      u      u
#  3:      3      c   753      u      u
#  4:      4      d   130      t      t
#  5:      5      e   126      t      t
#  6:      6      f    44      5      5
#  7:      7      g   325      4      4
#  8:     c1      h   710      u      u
#  9:     c1      h   307      4      4
# 10:     c1      i   264      4      4
# 11:     c2      j   708      u      u
# 12:     c2      j   769      u      u
# 13:     c3      k   742      u      u
# 14:     c3      l   559      u      u
# 15:     c3      m   181      2      2
# 16:     c3      m   138      t      t
```

The notion of using *symbols* (e.g., `on = .(walk >= rab)`) is nice but not always convenient, ergo your search for using `get(.)`. However, I believe *strings* are capable of controlling all types of joins that `data.table` supports, whether equality on the same name (`"cake"`), equality with different names (`"cake" == "cake2"`), or inequality (`"walk >= rab"`), and `data.table` will internally evaluate those in the context of the two datasets being joined. Since they are all strings, they can all be formed programmatically.

Important, though, is that one cannot use both *symbols* and *strings*, you must use all of one or the other. (I cannot think of a reason when using strings is ever inoptimal, since if you write `walk >= rab`, it only takes two more characters to write `"walk >= rab"`.)

Comment: Thanks evans, How about if I wish to dynamic reference ```rab``` also at the same time.

Comment: `paste(fromexcel, ">=", someothervariableyoumayhave)`?

Comment: I am not completely sure but for some reason i need the ```on = .```  which you removed. maybe I am not able to explain. but I tried this way which gives the same error as above. ```dark[road,"menti2" :=.(i.cat) ,   on = .(paste(fromexcel, ">= rab")) ]``` . Dont worry about the down voter. I will undo as soon as my issue is fixed.

Comment: Not sure why you think `on=.(...)` is required, for me it fails with `argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='paste(fromexcel, "'`. Every join I've tried recently that normally uses `on = .(...)` using _symbols_ (i.e., NSE) works when I convert them to _strings_ indicating the same. I don't know how better to say: `on=.(paste(...))` is going to fail, it is wrong; `on=c(paste(...), paste(...), paste(...))` that would be joining on three pairs (not part of your question) should work just fine.

Comment: I have mentioned 2 times and it is part of the question. That don’t change functionality of the code but only make the dynamic referencing work.

Comment: *"if I try to make a dynamic reference for the column walk the code throws error"* ... my code fixes that. If something else is failing with your real data, there is nothing I can do unless you are able to update your question so that _my_ code also fails with _your_ data.

Comment: probably I will post another question, but just incase if you know please reply. what if there is another criteria in ```on``` ,then is it possible to use get.
if we assume ```cake``` exist in both. is it possible to input ```walk``` dynamically.
```dark[road,"menti2" :=.(i.cat) ,   on = .(cake,walk >= rab) ]```

Comment: Make a character vector. How about `on = c("cake", "walk >= rab")` or `on = c("cake == cake", "walk >= rab")`. No matter how you form either of those (with `paste`, `sprintf`, or just vector-indexing), a whole character vector always and still works.

Comment: Said differently: there are clearly times when _symbols_ (i.e., `on = .(cake, walk >= rab)`) are not convenient, ergo your attempt to use `get`. However, I don't know of any time where character vectors (`on = c("cake", "walk >= rab")`) cannot cover _every type of join that `data.table` supports_, whether exact same-name (`"cake"` or more verbosely `"cake == cake"`), equality by different names (`"cake1 == cake2"`), or inequality (`"walk >= rab"`). Those are all _strings_ that `data.table` internally parses/evaluates in the context of both datasets, and strings can be formed programmatically.

Comment: @Mohit, I'm glad we were able to get to the final holdup in your question. I think the use of strings is "always safe" with no reservations. Hope it works. (Since you said you would undo the downvote, if you have not then please consider undoing it now. Thanks!)

Comment: everything is sorted. I am happy. probably next time i will frame my questions in a much better way.